Monitor outputs of Lenovo Dock not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04
I have my laptop connected to a Lenovo docking station via USB-C.
I upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04, and now my monitors are not being recognized when attached to the docking station, every other device attached to it works fine (Ethernet, peripherals, external storage) Neither displaylink nor HDMI output of the docking station work, while the HDMI output of the Laptop is perfectly fine.
The libraries for displaylink are installed and up to date.
> sudo apt install synaptics-repository-keyring
synaptics-repository-keyring is already the newest version (2022.01).
> sudo apt install displaylink-driver
displaylink-driver is already the newest version (6.0.0-24).

Anyone knows could be missing?

Please edit the question and give the actual version numbers involved. Ubuntu 22 and 24 are versions of Ubuntu Core.
